# Visual Studio 2019 - Step in

Tags: visual-studio-2019

I am currently using Visual Studio 2019, when I use the debug method `Step In (F11)` it prioritizes the command prompt over the actual Visual Studio 2019 program. How do I change it so that it will keep me within Visual Studio 2019 but open the command prompt on the side?

Answer (score 1):

### I had the same problem and googled a lot for this, here is the result in short and long story:

The  **short**  answer is : use  **SHIFT + ALT + F5**  instead of  **F5**  and the long answer with more details can be found here:
[Microsoft Documents for Visual Studio 2019](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/python/python-interactive-repl-in-visual-studio?view=vs-2019)

**VISUAL STUDIO 2019**

Here is the way to do this with SIMPLE  **COMBO**  KEY, It is more simple than first solution :)

1. Go to  **Tools**  menu
2. Go to  **Options**
3. Press  **Ctrl+E**  and search Keyboard // OR go to
    **Environment>Keyboard**
4. In right side type  **YOUR LANGUAGE NAME** (I am using Python for example )  in search bar(below of "Show commands
   containing" I mean)
5. Go down and select the proper result belong your language, ( for Python you can choose "PYTHON.EXECUTEININTERACTIVE" from the results)
6. Click on the box  **"Press shortcuts keys:"**  and specify your
   combo key.
7. Be aware that Visual Studio has a lot of default combination and combo keys
   and do not use any regular shortcut.( I used  **F8** )
8. Check the "Use new shortcut in:" and select your place that want to
   use this shortcut (I suggest to use **GLOBAL**)
9. Click Assign > OK > **Have Fun**